# R/Leaflet: making LayersControl appear after click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

Please see the following MWE:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("mymap"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(
        providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
        group = 'stamen',
        options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron, group = 'cartodb') %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c('stamen', 'cartodb'),
                       position = 'bottomleft')

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The standard behaviour of the LayerControl (addLayersControl) is to appear after the user hovers the icon. Instead, I would like to view the layer options after clicking it. The standard addLayersControl function does not offer such functionality. Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Have you looked into this option ? http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#control-layers-collapsed

Comment: Yes, that options makes it collapsed, which is good. But I dont know how to make it just open on click instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R but in JS you need to add the option `collapsed` onto your `L.control.layers`
Now, if you want to open the control, you have to call this :

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers").addClass("leaflet-control-layers-expanded");
```

If you want to close it :

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers").removeClass("leaflet-control-layers-expanded");
```